# Automated site map tree for asp.net localhost website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sitemap, sitemapprovider

We have a localhost-only asp.net 3.5 website VB.NET project which has say 200 aspx pages.

We have someone external doing UX/UI for it and he has asked for an existing "sitemap".

Basically we want to give him a tree view of it all, like:

```
Home
  - Contact Page
       - Message Received Thankyou
 - Products
       - Product A
       - Product B
Etc
```

Is there any tool that we can use to generate a HTML page or similar just to show all this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three options:

1. Create a [site map navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx) page on the site
2. You can use the ASP.NET TreeView in conjunction with the SiteMapDataSource control to achieve this:

   [Understanding and Extending the Site Navigation System in ASP.NET 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479338.aspx)

   [More information](http://codersbarn.com/post/2009/07/30/Fix-for-TreeView-Jumping-in-Firefox.aspx) (caveat, old blog of mine).
3. You could also use the [SEO Toolkit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/10/12/using-the-seo-toolkit-to-generate-a-sitemap-of-a-remote-web-site/) to generate a Sitemap in XML format